# TypeError: props.numberArray.map is not a function react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am getting 'TypeError: props.numberArray.map is not a function react' this error on fetching array from redux, It is working fine if I use redux's useSelector to fetch array data

component

```
 <Typography>Name:{props.name}</Typography> 
  {
     props.numberArray && props.numberArray.map(numbers=> 
          <Typography>{numbers} </Typography>)
 }
```

redux-connect

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) =>
{   
    return{
        name:state.name,
        numberArray:state.numberArray,
    }
}

const mapStateToDispatch = (dispatch) =>
{
    return{
           updateName:() =>dispatch(updateName('orange')),           
           numberArray:() =>dispatch(updateNumberArray(15)),
         }    
}
```

reducer

```
const initialState = { name:'apple', numberArray:[1,2,3,4]}    

const userReducer = createSlice({ name:'user',initialState,
    reducers:{
         updateName(state,action){ state.name = action.payload },
         updateNumberArray(state,action){ state.numberArray.push(action.payload)}
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `mapStateToProps` and `mapStateToDispatch` define the `numberArray` property so there is a collision.

The property `numberArray` is a function (instead of an array) because you have `numberArray:() => dispatch(updateNumberArray(15))` in the object returned by `mapStateToDispatch` function (by the way the correct name would be `mapDispatchToProps`)

I would rename `numberArray` to `updateNumberArray`

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
           updateName:() =>dispatch(updateName('orange')),           
           updateNumberArray:() =>dispatch(updateNumberArray(15))
})
```

In your component you just need to call `props.updateNumberArray()`